# Obj-C function not being called in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, swiftui

I have been working on an app that will install any application from a JSON list. No errors are printed in console, but my method from an Obj-C file is not getting called.

I was given permission to use the Obj-C code below, along with that I have had it working in non-SwiftUI applications. I am confused on why it doesn't work here as it would in a normal Swift UIKit application.

Code is shown below.

Main View

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var installer: AppInstaller?
    @State var externalUrl = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {

            TrackableScrollView(.vertical, showIndicators: true, contentOffset: $scrollViewContentOffset) {

                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 15) {
                    VStack(spacing: 10) {
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
                            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                ForEach(featuredApps.apps, id: \.id) { app in
                                    FeaturedAppView(image: app.image, download: app.ipa)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            
                                            UserDefaults.standard.set(app.name, forKey: "apptitle")
                                            print("Installing App")
                                            
                                            externalUrl = app.ipa
                                            
                                            // Method below doesn't seem to be working
                                            installer?.installApp(withURL: externalUrl) { error in
                                                if error != nil {
                                                    print("App Install Failed.")
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                        }).frame(height: 120)

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Objective-C Classes

```objectivec
//
//  Bridging-header.h
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#include "AppInstaller.h"


...

//
//  AppInstaller.m
//  App Installer
//
//  Created by CreatureSurvive on 2017-06-29.
//  Copyright © 2017 Low Budget Animation Studios. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppInstaller.h"


@implementation AppInstaller {
    NSString *_url;
}

- (void)installAppWithURL:(NSString *)downloadLink completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completion {
    
    // no need to create multiple URLsessions, lets cache this for the lifetime of the app
    static NSURLSession *session;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    });

    // create our task
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:[self manifestPostRequestWithURL:downloadLink]
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                                {
                                                    // the task completed without error do things
                                                    if (!error)
                                                    {
                                                        // parse the headers into a dictionary so we can get the download link from them
                                                        NSDictionary *headers = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                                                        // attempt to download our app
                                                        [self downloadAppWithManifestURL:[@"https://file.io/" stringByAppendingString:headers[@"key"]]];
                                                    }

                                                    // return the completion
                                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                        completion(error);
                                                    });
                                                }];
    // make sure we start the task
    [dataTask resume];
}

- (NSData *)manifestDataWithURL:(NSString *)downloadLink {
    // setup local variables
    NSString *appBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"general" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // create plist if it doesnt exist in our documents directory;
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"general.plist"]])
    {
        //copy new file to documents directory
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:appBundlePath toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"general.plist"] error:nil];
    }

    NSString *documentsDirectoryPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"general.plist"];

    // check if the our last url is equal to the new url
    if ((_url != nil) &! [_url isEqualToString:downloadLink])
    {
        // no need to update the manifest just return it
        return [fileManager contentsAtPath:documentsDirectoryPlistPath];
    }

    // get the existing manifest as a dictionary to edit
    NSMutableDictionary *manifestDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:documentsDirectoryPlistPath];

    // sets the url of the manifest to the requested download link
    manifestDict[@"items"][0][@"assets"][0][@"url"] = downloadLink;
    NSDictionary *apptitle = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apptitle"];
    manifestDict[@"items"][0][@"metadata"][@"title"] = apptitle;
    [manifestDict writeToFile:documentsDirectoryPlistPath atomically:YES];

    // return the path to our updated manifest
    return [fileManager contentsAtPath:documentsDirectoryPlistPath];
}


- (NSURLRequest *)manifestPostRequestWithURL:(NSString *)downloadLink
{
    NSString *boundary = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

    // set body of the request and insert our manifest data
    // this is ugly, but its the only way i've found that works
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"general.plist\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/x-plist\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[self manifestDataWithURL:downloadLink]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setup request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://file.io/?expires=1d"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    return [request copy];
}

- (void)downloadAppWithManifestURL:(NSString *)downloadLink
{
//    NSLog(@"path: %@", downloadLink);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=" stringByAppendingString:downloadLink]]];
    });
}
@end

...

//
// Created by Dana Buehre on 6/29/17.
// Copyright (c) 2017 Low Budget Animation Studios. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppInstaller : NSObject

- (void)installAppWithURL:(NSString *)downloadLink completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completion;

@end
```

Comment: `installer` is declared as an Optional (`AppInstaller?`). Where do you set that value? If it's nil, your method won't ever be called -- seems that it's likely that this is what is happening.

Comment: @jnpdx having it this way in other projects never deemed to be an issue. I haven't figured out how to set the value without more resulted errors.

Comment: "having it this way in other projects never deemed to be an issue" -- but you *have to* set it somewhere. If it's resulting in more errors, can you post your attempt at setting it? Because that clearly seems to be the issue. Also, please check my answer to you from yesterday and see if it resolved your issues.

Comment: It did solve the issue. The reason for no errors was because I was missing a simple plist file in my project. Excuse me for my mistakes.

Comment: If my answer from yesterday solved your issue, please use the green check mark to mark it as correct. Not sure which question you're talking about involving a plist file -- maybe this one with the location of the bridging header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further inspection I had noticed a plist missing in my project files. This plist is a placeholder for apps to install. Upon creating it my issue has been resolved. My apologies for making people waste time with trying to help me.

Comment: [Readme.md](https://github.com/CreatureSurvive/App-Installer) “Works sometimes, but not always for some reason. No clue why.”  You may be right, but you may also just have luck.